# Why does the constructor of TreeSet<E> accept the parameter super of E instead of extend of E

Tags: java, comparator

I'm reading the java source code and I've found things as below:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.util/newTreeSetEComparatorsuperEc.htm

I don't understand why the parameter of this constructor is `<? super E>`.

As my understanding, it should be `<? extend E>` instead of `<? super E>` because if E is comparable, the children of E must be comparable whereas the parents of E may be not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's consider three classes: `Drink`, `Juice extends Drink`, and `OrangeJuice extends Juice`.

If I want a `TreeSet<Juice>`, I need a comparator that will compare any two juices.  Of course a `Comparator<Juice>` will do this.

A `Comparator<Drink>` will also do this, because it is able to compare any two drinks, and thus any two juices.

A `Comparator<OrangeJuice>` will not do this.  If I wanted to add an `AppleJuice` to my set of juices, that is not compatible with this comparator as it can only compare orange juices.

Answer (score 7):

You create a sorted set of bananas. To do that, you need to be able to compare the bananas. You can thus use a comparator of bananas to do that. But if you have a comparator that can sort any kind of fruit (including bananas), then that'll work too. So you can also use a `Comparator<Fruit>` or even a `Comparator<Food>` to sort your bananas.

That's why a `Comparator<? super E>` is used.

If it was `Comparator<? extends E>`, you would be able to create a set of bananas with a `Comparator<DriedBanana>`. But that wouldn't work: a comparator of dried bananas can only compare dried bananas. Not all kinds of bananas.

For more information, also read [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Answer (score 4):

> it should be  instead of  because if E is
>   comparable, the children of E must be comparable whereas the parents
>   of E may be not.

`Comparator` doesn't rely on `Comparable` objects.
It is even often used as an alternative or a complement.

In fact, this constructor

```
public TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator) {...}
```

could have been :

```
public TreeSet(Comparator<E> comparator) {... }
```

But by specifying a lower bounded wildcard, JDK developers provided more flexibility for client classes by allowing the `Comparator` to be interoperable with both current class instances and parent class instances. In some cases, it may make sense.

Now this :

```
public TreeSet(Comparator<? extend E> comparator) {
```

cannot be valid as it means that you may finish with a `compare()` method that specifies subclass type as parameters .
But elements of the `Set` may contain instances of a specific subclass but not only.

Imagine this code :

```
TreeSet<CharSequence> set = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        ...
    }
});

set.add("string");
set.add(new StringBuilder());
...
```

I want compare `String`s but the `Set` could contain `String` instances but also any subclass of `CharSequence` such as `StringBuilder`, `CharBuffer`, etc... 
And if  `CharSequence` was not `abstract`, it could also contain instances of them.

With this example, we understand that conceptually  `Comparator<? extend E>` is wrong.